# Quadripedal Rigging: Twisted limbs

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm still pretty new to Blender. I have a quadripedal rig that I built from following an [online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mz6q7j0LV6A). I am trying to find out how much of the processes in this video are necessary because I've seen and read about different ways.

This is my rig.
[image]

In the tutorial, and in my blend, the IK limbs ended up twisted. He corrected his. I'm not able to as well as he did. Is there a standard way to prevent this in the future?

I set up pole targets, but how necessary are they really? I've seen rigs do without them and they seem to cause confusion (at least for me). Do the pole targets cause the twisting?

Finally, I have placed the IK constraints on the upper limb, as the video instructed. Is this best or is it better to use the lower limb?

Also, if anyone has any better suggestions for learning material on this topic I'm open to it. This was just the most recent tutorial I could find.

[image]

Comment: If you want to learn how to rig, here is a good tutorial series https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3wFcRXImVPOQpi-wi7uriXBkykXVUntv    Pole targets are to help the IK solver decide which way to bend the bones https://vimeo.com/171279647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IK constraint isnt pointing at the pole target the right way, you might want to try changing the pole angle[image]

also, looks like you need to recalculate the normals on your mesh because the leg looks flipped inside out.

Comment: Thanks man.  Really appreciate your time. These things, I don't know to look for yet.